# Why is table variable not working for SELECT INTO in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @TEMP_TBL TABLE (COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR(100)
SELECT ID, NAME INTO @TEMP_TBL  FROM TB1
```

above code is not woking where as below code is working. Why?

```
SELECT ID, NAME INTO TB2 FROM TB1
```

Comment: If you copied your SQL, your error is in that you didn't close the parenthesis on the first line properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing ending ")" in your query.
try this:

```
DECLARE @TEMP_TBL TABLE (COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TEMP_TBL
select ID, NAME FROM TB1
```

Answer (score 3):

It is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, not `SELECT ... INTO ...` like so:

```
INSERT INTO @TEMP_TBL 
SELECT ID, NAME FROM TB1
```

Comment: please see my question heading again...i have made correction

Comment: and also your code will not work

Comment: @RAKESHHOLKAR - Why it won't work??

Comment: @RAKESHHOLKAR You are missing a closing `)` in your code `TABLE (COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR(100) <--- here`

Answer (score 3):

SELECT... INTO creates a new table. If you want to create a temp Table yourself than you'll want to reverse it:

```
 DECLARE @TEMP_TBL TABLE (COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR(100))
 INSERT INTO @TEMP_TBL 
 SELECT ID, NAME FROM TB1
```